# opencv_createsamples.exe location for conda install

Tags: opencv, conda, haar-classifier, cascade-classifier

I am trying to create a cascade classifier for my program.The [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/dc/d88/tutorial_traincascade.html) mention using a script in order to help generate positive images, but I don't know where to get this script. I am wondering if the opencv_createsamples application is available for opencv installs via conda. How can I obtain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain the script executable by either building OpenCV v3 from source. The conda install will not include them. You will find the applications and how to build them in the repositorys apps folder

If you are on Linux there is a package available: `sudo apt get install libopencv`

After you install you can run `opencv_createsamples [options]`

[Manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/opencv_createsamples.1.html)